# Problemas al buscar un dato por ID en jpa

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, jpa, ejb

Buenas tardes a todos, estoy trabajando en un proyecto de practica para aumentar mis destrezas en JAVA EE, el hecho es que estoy haciendo un sistema de facturacion, usando JSF, JPA y PrimeFaces, tengo una pagina de facturacion y dentro de esta pagina tengo un  que toma el codigo_cliente de un cliente y usando ajax ejecuto un metodo para buscar la informacion de este. esta es una porcion del codigo factura.xhtml

```
<h:panelGrid id="gridBuscarDatosCliente" columns="4">
    <p:outputLabel value="Codigo del cliente" style="font-weight: bold"/>

    <p:inputText value="#{facturaBean.cliente.codigoCliente}" size="12">
        <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{facturaBean.agregarDatosCliente()}"
                update=":formularioFactura:gridDatosCliente"/>
    </p:inputText>

    <p:commandButton value="..." oncomplete="PF('dialogoClientes').show();"
                     update=":formularioFactura:dlgClientes"/>

    <p:outputLabel value="Fecha" style="font-weight: bold"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Esta es la seccion que pretendo que e actualice cada vez que se digite el codigo del cliente dentro del input:

```
<p:separator/>

<h:panelGrid id="gridDatosCliente">
    <p:outputLabel value="Nombre: " style="font-weight: bold"/>
    <p:outputLabel id="lblnombreCliente" value="#{facturaBean.cliente.nombre} #{facturaBean.cliente.apellido}" 
                   style="font-weight: bold"/>

    <p:outputLabel value="Direccion:   N/A" style="font-weight: bold"/>
    <p:outputLabel/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

y este es mi facturaBean

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.bean;

import com.pojo.Cliente;
import com.pojo.Factura;
import com.servicios.ClienteFacadeLocal;
import com.servicios.FacturaFacadeLocal;
import com.servicios.VendedorFacadeLocal;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Ana Sofia
 */
@Named(value = "facturaBean")
@RequestScoped
public class FacturaBean {


    @EJB
    private ClienteFacadeLocal clienteFacade;
    @EJB
    private FacturaFacadeLocal facturaFacade;


    //Este cliente es la llave foranea
    private Cliente cliente;
    private Factura factura;

    public FacturaBean() {
        cliente = new Cliente();
    }

    public ClienteFacadeLocal getClienteFacade() {
        return clienteFacade;
    }

    public void setClienteFacade(ClienteFacadeLocal clienteFacade) {
        this.clienteFacade = clienteFacade;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public Factura getFactura() {
        return factura;
    }

    public void setFactura(Factura factura) {
        this.factura = factura;
    }

    public void agregarDatosCliente(){

        factura.setCodigoCliente(clienteFacade.find(cliente.getCodigoCliente()));
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Correcto", "Datos del cliente agregado"));
    }
}
```

Que me recomiendan que haga. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola @Hildemy, exactamente cual es el problema? Leyendo tu pregunta no me queda claro. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según veo, lo que está intentando de hacer es un filtro por el código del Cliente (a medida que está digitando) para mostrarlo luego en la factura (siempre y cuando encuentra resultados). En este caso sería:

**factura.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
  <p:inputText value="#{facturaBean.codigoClienteFiltro}" size="12">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{facturaBean.agregarDatosCliente()}" update="@([id$=gridDatosCliente])"/>
  </p:inputText>


  <h:panelGrid id="gridDatosCliente">
    <p:outputLabel value="Nombre: " style="font-weight: bold"/>
    <p:outputLabel id="lblnombreCliente" value="#{facturaBean.factura.cliente.nombre} {facturaBean.factura.cliente.apellido}" style="font-weight: bold"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

**facturaBean**

@ViewScoped es el tipo de bean indicado para este caso, puesto que mantendrá la información de los datos mientras el usuario interactúe en la vista.

Sugiero declarar una variable del tipo según la base de datos (para este ejemplo será INT) para realizar el filtro y no olvidar implementar Serializable:

```
@ViewScoped 
public class FacturaBean implements Serializable{

  @EJB
  private ClienteFacadeLocal clienteFacade;

  private int codigoClienteFiltro;
  private Factura factura;

  // Setters y getters

  public void agregarDatosCliente(){
     try {
        if (!String.valueOf(codigoClienteFiltro).isEmpty()) { //validamos que no esté vacío
            factura = new Factura(); //instanciamos la clase Factura
            Cliente cliente = clienteFacade.find(codigoClienteFiltro); //Buscamos el cliente
            if (cliente != null) { //Si encontró el cliente ->
                factura.setCliente(cliente); //Asignamos el cliente a la factura
             }
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error al filtrar: " + e.getMessage());
     }
  }

}
```

Espero haya sido de ayuda.
Quedo atento a cualquier inquietud ;-)

Comment: Muchas gracias tu ayuda me ayudo mucho, habia decidido usar SessionScoped porque con el ViewScoped no me habia funcionado, pero ya me di cuenta en donde estaba fallando